# Given a list of points, how to determine which are within a certain distance of each other

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Give a list of 2d points and a maximum distance d, what is a better than O(n^2) way of finding which points are located within d from each point. I don't need a solution just some starting ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a spatial indexing structure such as kd tree and you can get O(n log n)

#### edit

Ah I think I misunderstood your comment. If you set n nearest neighbours in the query, in worst case a single search cost O (n log n) but you can put a flag on each found nearest points to denote whether they already belong to a particular cluster. Then you dont have to execute the nearest neighbour query again for those points. So final complexity is still O(n log n). Here's some more details on such range search http://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/cs6931/kdtree.pdf .

I am assuming here that the desired behaviour is to remove a point from consideration if it already belongs to a cluster. Perhaps you can clarify a bit on problem specification?

Comment: Thanks, I found this too. But what operations would we use on the tree to find all the points within maximum distance? That doesn't seem like a standard operation.

Comment: We can do k-th nearest neighbor with a k of n but then don't we have O (n * n * log n) ?

Comment: construction of kd tree O(n log n).then neighbourhood query for all points O(n log n). final complexity, you need to add them not multiply. so O (2 n log n)-> O(n log n)

Comment: if you need more details, have a look at dbscan related literature. it's not exactly the same as your task but close enough. kd tree, r* trees are typically used to bring the complexity to O(n log n)

Comment: I believe R-tree : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree is more suited for my task as stated, but I think my problem is simpler and I only have to find the nearest neighbor for each. So k-d tree will work.

Answer (score 0):

There can be n^2 point pairs to "find", so it's not really clear what you're after.

An "output-sensitive" way to do this whose running time is something like O(n log(n) + h), where h is the number of pairs you "find", is as follows:

- Sort the points in order by y coordinate.
- Sweep a line downward, throwing a point into a balanced binary tree when the sweep line hits it, and removing it once it's d above the sweep line.
- When you hit a point with the sweep line, iterate over everything in the balanced binary tree that's at most d left and at most d right of the new point.  "Find" every point that's within a distance d of the new point.

In the third bullet, if you have to look at k >= 6 points, there will be at least floor((k/6)^2) pairs to "find" (exercise!), so the number of pairs considered is proportional to the number of pairs "found."